# Is this formula correct, series and Bernoulli numbers

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

According to this page:
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Bernoulli_Numbers

The series is :
$\dfrac{x}{e^x-1}=1-\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{B_1x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{B_2x^4}{4!}+\dfrac{B_3x^6}{6!}...$
 where $B_1=-\dfrac{1}{2}, B_2=\dfrac{1}{6}, B_3=0, B_4=-\dfrac{1}{30}$

How can I expand obtain the Bernoulli coefficient as indicated in the website?

Using the series above, I have:

$\dfrac{x}{e^x-1}=1-\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{(-\frac{1}{2})x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{\frac{1}{6}x^4}{4!}+\dfrac{(0)x^6}{6!}...$

$=\dfrac{x}{e^x-1}=1-\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{x^2}{4}+\dfrac{x^4}{144}+0...$

This looks wrong since the series expansion according to Wolfram is:

$\dfrac{x}{e^x-1}=1-\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{x^2}{12}-\dfrac{x^4}{720}...$

But then the series of Wolfram doesn't show the Bernoulli number.
I am confused, can you help me here?

Comment: You may want to check the sign of $x^2 $ in the expansion of the 2nd equation. Also, on the same equation, where did the zero come from in the coefficient of $x^6$?

Comment: @NoChance: the third Bernoulli number is $0$

Comment: OK, May be you want to check the post below, look for the image with the formula #1541. The formula uses Even powers only - This may justify the inconsistent representation you found: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885685/important-identities-that-can-be-obtained-by-manipulating-the-function-fracx?rq=1

Comment: @NoChance: Do you know how can I expand this function into the series like Wolfram? Is there a way to expand this function and obtain the Bernoulli number before simplifying to get the equation in Wolfram?

Comment: I could only do Taylor's expansion, but since the calculations are tedious, I am not sure what we will get. This link may be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3420676/series-expansion-for-fx-fracxex-1?rq=1

Comment: @NoChance How about just expanding the series in the denominator? I have tried to directly use the Maclaurin formula and it is very tedious, not to mention that the derivatives are undefined.

Comment: you can use Taylor's at points other than zero. Expanding the denominator will not help since you can't manipulate $\frac{x}{a+b+c+d+....} $

Comment: @NoChance can you do this in the answer section?

Comment: @NoChance, the link above is asked by me. Unable to get a new answer, I post this question to get more people involved.

Comment: @NoChance Do you know how metamorphy get his answer?

Comment: I am not sure what the source of the answer is really.

Comment: @I think I can figure out the Bernoulli number part, I just need to know how to expand the series into Wolfram's form.

Comment: How about the Taylor series for $\dfrac{1}{e^x-1}$, I think we are close to get to the answer.

Comment: Yeh...its getting late, I missed the sign. The right expansion is very ugly - I tried on www.Symbolab.com (type Taylor followed by the function you wan to expand).

Comment: According to the page you linked, $\dfrac{x}{e^x-1}=1-\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{B_1x^2}{2!}\color{red}-\dfrac{B_2x^4}{4!}+\dfrac{B_3x^6}{6!}...$, and that is the archaic definition of Bernoulli numbers, according to which $B_3$ is not zero

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: can you have a look at this thread and help me out? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3420982/how-to-expand-the-series-dfrac1ex-1

Answer (score 1):

Note, the generating  function for the Bernoulli numbers is defined as
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_nx^n}{n!}
\end{align*}
with $\frac{B_\color{blue}{n}}{n!}$ the coefficient of  $x^\color{blue}{n}$.

> Since we have $B_0=1, B_1=-\frac{1}{2}, B_2=\frac{1}{6}, B_3=0, B_4=-\frac{1}{30},\ldots$ we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{x}{e^x-1}}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_nx^n}{n!}\\
> &=B_0+\frac{B_1x}{1!}+\frac{B_2x^2}{2!}+\frac{B_3x^3}{3!}+\frac{B_4x^4}{4!}+\cdots\\
> &=1+\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)x}{1}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)x^2}{2}+\frac{0x^3}{6}+\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{30}\right)x^4}{24}+\cdots\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{12}-\frac{x^4}{720}+\cdots}
> \end{align*}